# I got an issue after i migrated a site

Tags: images, database, code, troubleshooting

I recently migrated a site to a larger server. Everything appears to be fine, the site works everything transferred over. The site does have an SSL cert.

Recently we started to get flagged as unsafe on browsers set up for "safe browsing". When I went into the inspect tool under console there was some mixed content which I fixed by using a search and replace tool, so the bad files were relabeled to HTTPS.

The problem is I have 3 files that don't exist on the server, but are still being referenced by WordPress somewhere.

[image]

My question is:

1. what is the process for getting these off? Is it in the code? database? both? If so where would the code be located and/or which table(s) would i look?
2. is there a safe way to remove these?

Comment: note that plugin recommendations aren't on topic on this site, but without more information about those 3 files it's difficult to tell, e.g. the URLs, and the html on the page that references them. E.g. are they in the header? The post content? The footer? Somewhere else? Do they have the correct domain? Keep in mind those aren't 404's, they're 2 DNS name not resolved errors, and a request to somewhere that has an invalid certificate. For all we know it's a 3rd party JS library on another server at fault, it's impossible to tell with what you've provided

Comment: If you hover over the link of the items on the right side, you should get the whole requested URL, which should provide a clue. Clicking on the link should show you the source code for the error.
And if you go to the Network tab (on your screenshot), you should see the entire requested URL.
More clues to help you ... add to your question with that additional info, if needed.

Comment: Thanks guys..I figured out a simple work around. I just used migrate DB to search and replace the bad referenced to files that are already on the server. Worked perfectly. thanks again

Comment: Thanks guys..I figured out a simple work around. I just used migrate DB to search and replace the bad referenced to files that are already on the server. Worked perfectly. thanks again